# JSON Payload error | OpenAI API call error: we could not parse the JSON

Tags: json, openai-api

API call from openAI but sometimes i get this error

There was an issue setting up your call. Raw response for the API Status code 400 { “error”: { “message”: “We could not parse the JSON body of your request. (HINT: This likely means you aren’t using your HTTP library correctly. The OpenAI API expects a JSON payload, but what was sent was not valid JSON. If you have trouble figuring out how to fix this, please send an email to support@openai.com and include any relevant code you’d like help with.)”, “type”:
“invalid_request_error”, “param”: null, “code”: null } }

Using Parameter as

```
Constants for API endpoint and request properties
Const API_ENDPOINT As String = "https://api.openai.com/v1/completions"
Const MODEL As String = "text-davinci-003"
Const MAX_TOKENS As String = "1024"
Const TEMPERATURE As String = "0.5"


Prompt 

          ' Get the prompt
          Dim prompt As String
80        prompt = ActiveCell.Value

          ' Check if there is anything in the selected cell
90        If Trim(prompt) <> "" Then
              ' Clean prompt to avoid parsing error in JSON payload
100           prompt = CleanJSONString(prompt)
110       Else
120           MsgBox "Please enter some text in the selected cell before executing the macro", vbCritical, "Empty Input"
130           Application.ScreenUpdating = True
140           Exit Sub
150       End If



Passing Prompt Value 

Analyse below data and find Employee Name having highest salary
Employee Name   Salary  Position    Joining Date
Jack    20303   Developer   01-Jan-22
Tinus   32444   Senior Consultant   02-Jan-22
Dave    57644   Manager 03-Jan-22
Manika  9665    Assistant   04-Jan-22
Sumit   23443   Analyst 05-Jan-22   



Failing at below exception , Kindly suggest

    Else
440           MsgBox "Request failed with status " & httpRequest.Status & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "ERROR MESSAGE:" & vbCrLf & httpRequest.responseText, vbCritical, "OpenAI Request Failed"
450       End If
```

Tried to pass one liner question working fine but not at data range